# How to set same variable as string and as List in serialization using Java

Tags: java, json, serialization, rest-assured

I have a code below of JSON and I want to post it using Rest Assured in Java

```
{
  "Document1": [
    {
      "UserName": " ABC",
      "UserNo": "1234"
    },
    {
      "UserName": " DEF",
      "UserNo": [
        "2345",
        "4567"
      ]
    },
    {
      "UserName": " MNO",
      "UserNo": "1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created getter setter for the Username and UserNo

```
public class Document1{

    private String UserName;
    private String UserNo
    
    public String getUserName(){
       return UserName;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("UserName")
    public void setUserName(String userName){
       UserName = userName;
    }
    
    public String getUserNo(){
       return UserNo;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("UserNo")
    public void setUserNo(String userNo){
       UserNo = userNo;
    }
}
```

Here `UserNo` sometimes accepts as string and sometimes as List.
But it's not same for all UserNo
`Eg: UserName :"ABC"` accepts `UserNo` as string
and  `UserName :"DEF"` accepts `UserNo` as List
if I change UserNo as

```
    private List<String> UserNo;
    
    public List<String> getUserNo(){
       return UserNo;
    }
    
    @JsonProperty("UserNo")
    public void setUserNo(List<String> userNo){
       UserNo = userNo;
    }
```

It works for `UserName:DEF` but it fails for `UserName:ABC`
how to pass list of string as Serialization`UserNo` for which some `UserNo` accepts and some fails  ?
Below is the class for post

```
public class addUser{
    
    CreateUser cu = new CreateUser();
    
    List<Document1> dc1 = new ArrayList();
    
    Document1 d1 = new Document1();
    d1.setUserName("ABC");
    d1.setUserNo("1234");
    dc1.add(d1);
    
    Document1 d2 = new Document1();
    d2.setUserName("DEF");
    d2.setUserNo("2345");
    dc1.add(d2);    
}
```

Comment: UserNo cannot be both a `String` and a `List<String>`. This cannot be done using one json field. Either make it a `List<String>` which sometimes only contains one value or create a second field so that both cases are covered.

Comment: Is it not simplier to have a List<String> for both of cases ? Sometimes with one element, sometimes with several.

Comment: When I tried with `List<String>` I'm getting 500 server error but if I try without that it works for `String` not for `List<String>` @f1sh @Majestic

Comment: Yes, because your payload still covers both cases.

Comment: But when I try it as `List<String>`, I get 500 error i.e., `"UserNo":["1234"]` . But my requirement is that `"UserName":"ABC"` should have only one value i.e., `"UserNo":"1234"` which is a String but `"UserName":"DEF"` can have more than one value i.e `"UserNo":["2345","4567"]`

Comment: @mohammedazharuddin There is simplest way to do that set `private Object UserNo`, then you can supply both type: `String` and `List`.